# NetBeans 8.2 freeze after main interface shows

Tags: netbeans

My NetBeans 8.2 is freezing after it starts up. I installed 8.2 yesterday, use it about one hour and close it. A few hours latter, I tried to use it again, and it freezes. I uninstalled everything, installed 8.1, use it and in the second startup 8.1 starts to show the same behavior (it was working since it was released). I uninstalled 8.1, installed 8.2 again. It works in the first use, but after that it starts freezing.

It is only working after uninstall/install. I already tried to delete C:\Users{my_user}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans 8.x and it does not work too. I updated my JDK to the last version (u112, I was using u92) and the same problem persists.

Below is the messages.log content:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Thursday, November 10, 2016 7:02:15 PM BRST
>System Info:
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) (#5fd841261bf9)
  Operating System        = Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_112; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.112-b15; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_112-b15
  Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (nb); Cp1252
  Home Directory          = C:\Users\David
  Current Directory       = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2
  User Directory          = C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2
  Cache Directory         = C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2
  Installation            = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\ergonomics
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\ide
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\extide
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\apisupport
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\webcommon
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\websvccommon
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\enterprise
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\profiler
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\php
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\harness
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\javafx
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\classes;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
  Application Classpath   = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\boot.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\org-openide-util-lookup.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\org-openide-util-ui.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\org-openide-util.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\boot_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\boot_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\boot_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\boot_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-ui_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-ui_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-ui_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-ui_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\lib\dt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\lib\tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\asm-all-5.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\core-base.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\core.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\core-base_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\core-base_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\core-base_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\core-base_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\core_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\core_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\core_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\core_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-netbeans-libs-asm_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-netbeans-libs-asm_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-netbeans-libs-asm_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-netbeans-libs-asm_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems-compat8_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems-compat8_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems-compat8_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems-compat8_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\org-netbeans-upgrader.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\locale\core_nb.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\locale\core_nb_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\locale\core_nb_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\locale\core_nb_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\locale\core_nb_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/C:/Program Files/NetBeans 8.2/
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
   org.openide.util.lookup [8.33.1 201609300101]
   org.openide.util [9.7.1 201609300101]
   org.openide.util.ui [9.6.1 201609300101]
   org.openide.modules [7.48.1 201609300101]
   org.netbeans.api.annotations.common/1 [1.27.1 201609300101]

   // lots of other modules here...

   org.eclipse.equinox.app [1.3.100 1.3.100.v20110321]
   org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth [3.2.200 3.2.200.v20110110]
   org.eclipse.core.net [1.2.100 1.2.100.I20110511-0800]
   org.eclipse.core.contenttype [3.4.100 3.4.100.v20110423-0524]
   org.apache.xmlrpc [3.0.0 3.0.0]
   org.apache.ws.commons.util [1.0.1 1.0.1]
   org.apache.commons.lang [2.6 2.6]
   org.apache.commons.codec [1.3.0 1.3.0]
   com.jcraft.jzlib [1.0.7 1.0.7]
   com.googlecode.javaewah.JavaEWAH [0.7.9 0.7.9]
   com.google.guava [15.0.0 15.0.0]
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.9.1.v20140110-1610 started
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy resolver: Windows
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy reloading succeeded.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy - mode: direct
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy: fell to default (correct if direct mode went before)
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
   -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade
   -Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense
   -client
   -Xss2m
   -Xms32m
   -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
   -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
   -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
   -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true
   -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
   -Xmx1024m
   -Djdk.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
   -Djdk.launcher.addexports.0=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
   -Djdk.launcher.addexports.1=java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs=ALL-UNNAMED
   -Djdk.launcher.addexports.2=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED
   -Djdk.launcher.addexports.3=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED
   -Djdk.launcher.addexports.3=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED
   -Djdk.launcher.addexports.4=java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows=ALL-UNNAMED
   -Djdk.launcher.addexports.5=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
   -Dnetbeans.home=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform
   -Dnetbeans.user=C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2
   -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans
   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
   -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\var\log\heapdump.hprof
   -Dsun.awt.keepWorkingSetOnMinimize=true
   -Dnetbeans.dirs=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\nb;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\ergonomics;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\ide;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\extide;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\apisupport;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\webcommon;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\websvccommon;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\enterprise;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\mobility;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\profiler;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\python;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\php;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\identity;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\harness;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\cnd;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\cndext;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\dlight;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\groovy;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\extra;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\javacard;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\javafx
   exit
Compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
Heap memory usage: initial 32.0MB maximum 910.5MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 2.4MB maximum -1b
Garbage collector: PS Scavenge (Collections=9 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: PS MarkSweep (Collections=2 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=6357 total loaded=6357 unloaded 0
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 8,478,961,664
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogParser]: Unpaired license 00000008 without any module.
```

Does anyone know what may be happening?

Comment: Did the log have any additional information when it froze?

Comment: @Seth unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

In these situations what is needed to diagnose the problem precisely is a **thread dump**. It will very often give the clue as to why there's a freeze.

NetBeans IDE is build on Java and Java has 5 or 6 different ways to obtain a thread dump for a running application (just google it). Out of these methods, the one preferred is the so-called [Ctrl-Break method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr019.html) because it is the one which gives most information. The downside of the method is that you need to have started your application (in this case the NetBeans IDE) from a console window. But if you can consistently replicate the freeze, then I don't think that's a problem for you. Here's what you would do if you are on Windows:

1. Start `cmd.exe`
2. From the command window, start your application, e.g. `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans64.exe`.
3. Wait for the freeze to happen.
4. Now press Ctrl-Break *in the command window* from step 1. This will give you a thread dump printed into your command window.
5. Upload the thread dump as part of your question. (or host it somewhere if it is too big)

Instructions for Linux/MacOSX are similar albeit in step 4 you would instead send your process a `QUIT` signal using the kill command.

Comment: Started cmd as admin, gave command correctly, Netbeans 8.2 started, did one Debug step and freeze. Alt+Tab to command prompt and press Break, Fn+Break, Ctrl+Break, and Ctrl+Fn+Break NO DUMP. Note: Fn+Break interrupts Excel VBA Msgbox, so it works. Upon starting Netbeans, launcher says `The launcher has determined that the parent process has a console and will reuse it for its own console output.
Closing the console will result in termination of the running program.
Use '--console suppress' to suppress console output.
Use '--console new' to create a separate console window. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realy can't say if it's 100% certain, but it seems to be something related, in my case, with how my monitors are being used. With extended desktop, NetBeans freezes. Showing only the main monitor or only the secondary one, it works normally. I will not mark this answer as correct until somebody can confirm it.

Comment: you may be right, I face this after using dual monitor. But idk how to fix it on linux since, when it buggy my linux mint only detect 1 display. With 3 attempts to launch it, finally,  it working. However, I try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819991/netbeans-suddenly-failed-to-start-after-saying-done-loading-modules before this one.